# Why is the 64-bit version of Chrome more stable than the 32-bit

Tags: google-chrome, 64-bit

When Google first released the 64-bit version of Chrome to the Canary and Dev channels they stated that:

> **Stability**: Finally, we’ve observed a marked increase in stability for 64-bit Chrome over 32-bit Chrome. In particular, crash rates for the the renderer process (i.e. web content process) are almost half that of 32-bit Chrome.

http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/try-out-new-64-bit-windows-canary-and.html

What exactly would make the 64-bit version more stable? Is there something about recompiling to 64-bit that makes it more stable, or was there some retooling under the hood that had this effect?